# Invalid Identifier when using ArrayList<Character>

Tags: java, arrays, list, equals, system.out

I am trying to finish this program for a homework assignment and This is the only thing not working. I get an expected error on this line:

> System.out.println(myChars.equals(complement));

Here is my code

```
public class WCpalindrome {
  private static char[] dna = {'A', 'C', 'T', 'G'};
  private static ArrayList<Character> myChars = new ArrayList<Character>();
  private static ArrayList<Character> reverse = new ArrayList<Character>();
  private static ArrayList<Character> complement = new ArrayList<Character>();


public static char toUpperCase(char c) {
  if (c == 'A' || c == 'a') {
    return 'A';
  } else if (c == 'T' || c == 't') {
    return 'T';
  } else if (c == 'C' || c == 'c') {
    return 'C';
  }
  return 'G';
}

public static char getComplement(char c) {
  if (c == 'A' || c == 'a') {
    return 'T';
  } else if (c == 'T' || c == 't') {
    return 'A';
  } else if (c == 'C' || c == 'c') {
    return 'G';
  }
  return 'C';
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

  char current;
  int i = 0;

  //Get the input sequence
  while (StdIn.hasNextChar()) {
    current = StdIn.readChar();
    current = toUpperCase(current);
    myChars.add(current);
    StdOut.println(myChars.get(i));
    i++;
  }

  System.out.println();

  //Reverse the sequence
  int k = 0;
  int size = myChars.size() - 1;
  for (int j = size-1; j >= 0; j--) {
    current = myChars.get(j);
    StdOut.println(current);
    reverse.add(k, current);
    k++;
  }

  System.out.println();

  //Complement the reversed sequence
  int n = 0;
  size = myChars.size() - 1;
  for (n = 0; n < size; n++) {
    current = reverse.get(n);
    complement.add(getComplement(current));
    StdOut.println(complement.get(n));
  }
}

//Prints true if the original equals the complement of the reversal
//else it prints false
System.out.println(myChars.equals(complement));
```

}

Comment: When should that line be executed?

Answer (score 3):

The line you are talking about is not inside any method. I think you want to move it inside your main method.

Answer (score 0):

You have place the statement `System.out.println(...);` outside `main()`. Shift it up 3 lines. It is now at the level where method and field declarations are expected.

Also the equals will always return false as array instances do not compare there inside elements.
`One might use`Arrays.equals` but you might simply use:

```
System.out.println(new String(myChars).equals(new String(complement)));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.println(myChars.equals(complement));
```

outside of main method.

this should be in end

```
  }
//Prints true if the original equals the complement of the reversal
    //else it prints false
    System.out.println(myChars.equals(complement));
}
}
```